how to rectify unwanted github actions?
I have a PR here https://github.com/oscal-compass/compliance-trestle/pull/1550. It has updated workflows, specifically changing versions of python from 3.7,3.8,3.9 to 3.9,3.10,3.11. Yet the github actions seem to remember the the previous workflow as well and insist on using 3.8, for example: test (macos-latest, 3.8) Expected — Waiting for status to be reported? How do I get rid of the the three Expected tests that don't belong?

you need to goto settings -> Branches -> edit target branch -> under "Status checks that are required." you need to delete test jobs that are not required.
